# $R/I$ and $I$ are Artinian rings. Is $R$ Artinian?

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R/I$ and $I$ be Artinian rings. Must $R$ be Artinian?

Considering a sequence of ideals $\{I_n\}$ with $\subseteq$ and after using correspondence theorem, can I claim that there exists $k$ such that $I_{k+i}/I \subseteq I_k/I=I \cdots$

Comment: your claim is true but show some steps atleast

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If all of the $I_i$'s are trapped in $I$, then you can see what to do.

On the other hand, if the chain escapes $I$, then you have another increasing sequence $(I_i+I)/I$ in $R/I$.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $0 \to I \to R \to R/I \to 0$ is an exact sequence.

If you have the following result at your disposal, you're done:

**Lemma**: Let $0 \to M' \xrightarrow \alpha M \xrightarrow \beta M'' \to 0$ be an exact sequence of $R$-modules. Then $M$ is Artinian if and only if $M'$ and $M''$ are Artinian.